# How to test If onClick calllback renders isactive state when tite is clicked?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I tried to write test for the onClick callback in this component:

```
const Accordion = ({ children, text, color, activeColor }) => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false)
  return (
  <Styled.Accordion color={color}>
      <Styled.Title
        variant="h5"
        as="div"
        onClick={() => setIsActive(!isActive)}
        color={isActive ? activeColor : color}
      >
        {text}
        <Styled.Icon isActive={isActive}>
          <Icon name="arrowUp" />
        </Styled.Icon>
      </Styled.Title>
      {isActive && <Styled.Content>{children}</Styled.Content>}
    </Styled.Accordion>
)
}
```

basically I wrote it like this:

```
describe(`Accordion`, () => {
it(`fires isActive state when title is clicked`, () => {
    const isActive = jest.fn()
    render(<Accordion onClick={isActive} />)
    fireEvent.click(isActive)
    expect(isActive).toHaveBeenCalledWith(false)
  })
```

But it fails. Could you please advise what is wrong with it? I would like to write a test to check if isActive state renders, after clicking on the accordion's title.

Comment: It [still](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75355620/how-to-write-a-test-in-jest-for-onclick-function#comment132966269_75355620) (third time? Maybe you deleted one) doesn't take `onClick` as a property. You can pass the test double all you like, but it's ignored by the component and completely unconnected to the behaviour you're trying to test.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are setting the `color` property. Looks like it should be inside the `style` property.

Add `data-testId` property to your `Styled.Ttile`:

```
  <Styled.Title data-testId="accordion-title">
```

Then you can check if the style was changed after clicking. This is more like the direction than the exact solution.

```
it(`marks accordion as active after click`, () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<Accordion activeColor="red" />);

  const accordionTitle = getByTestId('accordion-title');

  fireEvent.click(accordionTitle)

  expect(accordionTitle).toHaveStyle({color: 'red'});
});
```

Comment: You likely don't need a test ID, you can select headers by role.

Comment: Yeap, good idea.